# How to access the first element in an object which implemented IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net

Only want to access the first element in an object which implemented IEnumerable, how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can’t use the LINQ extension methods on something which implements only `IEnumerable`. You can, however, use `.Cast<object>()` to turn it into an `IEnumerable<object>` and then use the following methods. The following assumes that `collection` is of type `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`:

To access the first element and throw an exception if there is none:

```
collection.First()
```

To access the first element and get the type’s default value if there is none:

```
collection.FirstOrDefault()
```

The type’s default value is `null` for reference types (types declared as `class`, for example `string`, `Stream`, `Bitmap`, etc.) and the “zero value” for value types (types declared as `struct` or `enum`, for example `int`, `bool`, `DateTime`, etc.).

To only find out whether there is a first element at all:

```
collection.Any()
```

All three of these can take a lambda expression as a condition, e.g. `.First(x => x.Name == "x")`, which is equivalent to `.Where(x => x.Name == "x").First()`.

Comment: I don't find those methods. My object only implemented IEnumable interface.

Comment: can you please show any reference for your first sentence? (`Unfortunately you can’t use the LINQ extension methods on something which implements only IEnumerable`). I have copied my sample from the MSDN page and it just use an array of int...thanks!

Comment: @user496949: See my updated answer, especially the first sentence. @Lorenzo: `int[]` implements not just `IEnumerable` but also `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 4):

use the [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method

```
using System.Linq;

int[] numbers = { };
int first = numbers.FirstOrDefault();
```